# Why does Visual Studio unit test code and result view open in two different window panes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This question is best illustrated with a series of screenshots:

[image: I click "Open Test"]

..the class file with the test code opens

[image: I click "Open Result View"]

..and the Result view opens in a different area:

[image]

Super annoying! Anyone know how to fix this?